# Javafx advanced Candle Stick chart does not draw the candle

Tags: java, javafx, candlestick-chart

I am just copying and pasting the source code [from here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Charts/Custom/Adv%20Candle%20Stick%20Chart) (may not work on chrome).

When I run the code, it does not draw the boxes as advertised.

I don't think I can post images, but all I get after running is the stick and the line graph of the average price. I don't get the green or red box. Am I missing something that doesn't let my program draw? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
candleWidth = xa.getDisplayPosition( xa.getTickUnit() ) * 0.90; // use 90% width between ticks.
```

Comment out this line and the candlestick bodies return. Also include the CSS files. The source code is incomplete on its own